# Zero-dimensional ring with infinitely many maximal ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

I am searching for a commutative ring with zero Krull dimension which have infinitely many prime ideals.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: Any such ring will necessarily have to be non-Noetherian. Any Noetherian ring with dim 0 is Artinian - which is a finite product of Artinian local rings, and so has only finitely many primes. An infinite product of Artinian local rings should work though.

Comment: Consider the direct product of infinitely many fields, say $\mathbb Q^{\aleph_0}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class of these rings can be totally classified as the class of rings having nil Jacobson radical $J(R)$ and having $R/J(R)$ a nonNoetherian von Neumann regular ring.

So an infinite product of fields works, or an infinite product of commutative VNR rings works. You could also take any (nonzero) module over such a ring and the idealization of the module would give you a version with nontrivial Jacobson radical.